# Function Problems Checking Numbers against stored numbers in an Array

Tags: javascript

I am very very new to javaScript and i am currently writing a program to check lottery numbers against 3 hard coded draws. the problem i have is that the functions to check the numbers against each other don't seem to work. I also want to incorporate a duplicate entry checker where if a duplicate number is entered it asks for another number but don't know how to do this. Lastly i want to have the inputs maximum value 49 and minimum value of one.

The problem is that if the numbers all match the output is just 1 not 6, if no numbers match the output is still 1.

Here is the Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lotto Checker</title>
    <script>

        function checkerOne(drawOne, guess) {
            var i, j, count;
            count = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++);
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 6; j++);
                {
                    if (drawOne[i] == guess[j]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
        function checkerTwo(guess, drawTwo) {
            var i, j, count;
            count = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++);
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 6; j++);
                {
                    if (guess[i] == drawTwo[j]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }
        function checkerThree(guess, drawThree) {
            var i, j, count;
            count = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 6; i++);
            {
                for (j = 0; j < 6; j++);
                {
                    if (guess[i] == drawThree[j]);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            return count;
        }

        var date = new Date();
        var n = date.toDateString();
        var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
        var count2;
        var drawOne = new Array();
        var drawTwo = new Array()
        var drawThree = new Array()
        var guess = new Array();
        var bonus = 45;
        var bonusGuess;
        drawOne[0] = 8
        drawOne[1] = 11
        drawOne[2] = 19
        drawOne[3] = 23
        drawOne[4] = 28
        drawOne[5] = 36


        drawTwo[0] = 2
        drawTwo[1] = 9
        drawTwo[2] = 16
        drawTwo[3] = 25
        drawTwo[4] = 39
        drawTwo[5] = 41


        drawThree[0] = 7
        drawThree[1] = 14
        drawThree[2] = 22
        drawThree[3] = 30
        drawThree[4] = 37
        drawThree[5] = 49
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        count2 = 0;
        do {
            guess[0] = window.prompt("Enter your first number:");
            guess[1] = window.prompt("Enter your second number:");
            guess[2] = window.prompt("Enter your third number:");
            guess[3] = window.prompt("Enter your fourth number:");
            guess[4] = window.prompt("Enter your fifth number:");
            guess[5] = window.prompt("Enter your sixth number:");
            bonusGuess = window.prompt("Enter Your Bonus Ball:");
            count2++;


            document.write("The Numbers Drawn this week were: ", drawOne, " The Bonus Ball Was: ", bonus, "<br/>")
            document.write("Your Numbers Are: ", guess, " Your Bonus Ball Is: ", bonusGuess, "<br/>")


            if (checkerOne(drawOne, guess) >= 5 && bonusGuess == bonus) {
                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerOne(drawOne, guess)), " Numbers! You have also matched the Bonus Ball!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")
            }
            else if (checkerOne(drawOne, guess) >= 3)

                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerOne(drawOne, guess)), " Numbers!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            if (checkerOne(drawOne, guess) < 3) {
                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerOne(drawOne, guess)), " Numbers! You haven't won this time!</br>")
            }
            document.write((n + ' ' + time), "</br>");
            document.write("</br>")

            document.write("The Numbers Drawn this week were: ", drawTwo, " The Bonus Ball Was: ", bonus, "<br/>");
            document.write("Your Numbers Are: ", guess, " Your Bonus Ball Is: ", bonusGuess, "<br/>")



            if (checkerTwo(guess, drawTwo) >= 5 && bonusGuess == bonus) {
                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerTwo(guess, drawTwo)), " Numbers! You have also matched the Bonus Ball!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")
            }
            else if (checkerTwo(guess, drawTwo) >= 3)

                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerTwo(guess, drawTwo)), " Numbers!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            if (checkerTwo(guess, drawTwo) < 3) {
                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerTwo(guess, drawTwo)), " Numbers! You haven't won this time!</br>")
            }
            document.write((n + ' ' + time), "</br>");
            document.write("</br>")

            document.write("The Numbers Drawn this week were: ", drawThree, " The Bonus Ball Was: ", bonus, "<br/>");
            document.write("Your Numbers Are: ", guess, " Your Bonus Ball Is: ", bonusGuess, "<br/>")
            document.write("The Number of Matches you have is: ", checkerThree(guess, drawThree), "</br>")


            if (checkerThree(guess, drawThree) >= 5 && bonusGuess == bonus) {
                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerThree(guess, drawThree)), " Numbers! You have also matched the Bonus Ball!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")
            }
            else if (checkerThree(guess, drawThree) >= 3)

                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerThree(guess, drawThree)), " Numbers!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            if (checkerThree(guess, drawThree) < 3) {
                document.write("You Matched ", (checkerThree(guess, drawThree)), " Numbers! You haven't won this time!</br>")
            }
            document.write((n + ' ' + time), "</br>");
            document.write("</br>")
        }
        while (guess[i] != guess[i])


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Since you're new, here you are some tips: 1) The language is called JavaScript (one word). It has nothing to do with the Java language. 2) Find your browser developer tools. They provide invaluable info. 3) "Does not work" is the poorest problem description ever.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that if the numbers all match the output is just 1 not 6, if no numbers match the output is still 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty obvious that there is much improvement that can be done to the code when all the answers prefer to rewrite it than to spot the error.

The problem you had was with the control structures in the checkerX functions:

```
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++);
```

That iterates over something, but doesn't actually excute code (because of the `;` which ends the statement). Same thing goes for the `if`. Practically your function increments `count` once and returns it (thus you see 1 for all cases).

Anyway, i rewrote the code to be much more concise, but still in line with the original idea:

```
function check(draw, guess) {
    var i, j, count;
    count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (draw[i] == guess[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

// presets
var draws = [
    [8, 11, 19, 23, 28, 36],
    [2, 9, 16, 25, 39, 41],
    [7, 14, 22, 30, 37, 49]
];
var bonus = 45;

// guesses
var questions = [
    "Enter your first number:",
    "Enter your second number:",
    "Enter your third number:",
    "Enter your fourth number:",
    "Enter your fifth number:",
    "Enter your sixth number:"
];

var guess = [];
questions.forEach(function(text) {
    do {
        var entry = window.prompt(text);
    } while (guess.indexOf(entry) !== -1 || +entry < 1 || +entry > 49);
    guess.push(entry);
});

var bonusGuess = window.prompt("Enter Your Bonus Ball:");

// checking
for (var i = 0; i < draws.length; i++) {
    var matched = check(draws[i], guess);

    document.write("The Numbers Drawn this week were: ", draws[i], " The Bonus Ball Was: ", bonus, "<br/>");
    document.write("Your Numbers Are: ", guess, " Your Bonus Ball Is: ", bonusGuess, "<br/>");

    document.write("You Matched ", matched, " Numbers!");   
    if (matched >= 5 && bonusGuess == bonus) {
        document.write(" You have also matched the Bonus Ball!");
    }

    if (matched >= 3) {
        document.write("</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>");
    } else {
        document.write(" You haven't won this time!</br>");
    }

    var date = new Date();
    document.write((date.toDateString() + ' ' + date.toLocaleTimeString()), "</br></br>");
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/AjUVoga/2/edit

Some things to note:

- Never copy-paste a function. All 3 functions named checkerX executed the same code (except one had the parameters reversed for some reason, but it didn't affect the result)
- arrays can be initialized with values already stored. These values can be references to other arrays (see **draws**)
- when you're doing the same thing for multiple values, either refactor it in a function or iterate over an array, preferably both!
- don't use document.write (i expect that is testing code, so i didn't touch it, but please don't use it for a real application)
- don't compute the same thing more than once. save the result and use that instead of calling the function each time you need the result (see **check**)
- i also rewrote your output conditions to be slightly easier to understand

The following piece of code

```
do {
  var entry = window.prompt(text);
} while (guess.indexOf(entry) !== -1 || +entry < 1 || +entry > 49);
guess.push(entry);
```

asks the user for input until the input matches your conditions: is unique, is larger or equal to 1 and is smaller or equal to 49. You might want to add a regex check to make sure it's a number:

```
|| !entry.match(/^\d{1,2}$/);
```

Comment: Thanks for all your quick responses and help. Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To solve your issue, you really need to define a few well defined functions each solving one clear problem.
As your code is now, there are a lot of redundancies, which is confusing, time consuming, and error prone.
So just a few ideas to get you near, i didn't test the code so re-read carefully, but you'll get the idea :

```
// checks n is a valid entry
function withinBounds(n) {
    return n>=1 && n<=50 ;
}

// provides a valid lotery number
function randNumber() {
     return 1 + Math.trunc ( 50  * Math.random()  ) ;
}

// ask user for a new number to be added to currentNumbers array. 
// Check boundaries and non-redundancy.
function promptForOneNumber(currentNumbers) {
      var correctNumberReturned = false;
      var guess=0;
      while (!correctNumberReturned) {
          var message  = "Enter the number " + (currentNumbers.length + 1) + " : \n";
          if (currentNumbers.length) 
                  message     += "current numbers : " + currentNumbers.join('  ');
          guess = window.prompt( message );
          if (withinBound(guess) && (currentNumbers.indexOf(guess)<0))
              correctNumberReturned=true;
      }
     currentNumbers.push(guess);
}

// ask users for all numbers of a new board and return it.
function promptForNumbers() {
    var newGuess = [];
    // basically, call promptForOneNumber 6 times...
    for (var i=0; i<6; i++ ) promptForOneNumber(newGuess);
    return newGuess;
}

// returns the count of good results for this guess
function checkResult ( guessed, final ) {
     var matchCount = 0;
     for (var i=0 ; i< guessed.length; i++) {
         var thisGuessed = guessed[i] ;
         if (final.indexOf(thisGuessed) >= 0) matchCount++;
     }
     return matchCount;
}

function greetUser ( matchCount ) {
    // ... do a switch on matchCount

}

// ....
function createRandomBoard() {
     var newBoard = [] ;
     var newNum = 0;
     for (var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
         do {
            newNum = randNumber();
         } while (newBoard.indexOf(newNum)>0);
         newBoard.push(newNum);
     }
}

// one attempts will go like :
var board1      = createRandomBoard ();
var userAttempt = promptForNumbers();
var score       = checkResult ( userAttempt, board1 ) ;
greetUser       ( score ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a number of issues that make me uncomfortable with this code.

The first is the way you've used and declared the functions that test user guesses against the draws. - You've used three functions, when just one would be sufficient. Since you give the function two arguments, why not make them the guessArray and the drawArray?

The next is that you continually re-calculate the number of matching guesses throughout your code. You can just store 3 numbers and re-use them - the number of matches for each of the 3 draws.

Another is the meaningless do-while loop. Since `guess[i]` will *always* equal `guess[i]`, there's no difference between your code and code that omits the do-while construct entirely.

Hard-coding the number 6 into all of your 3 functions is also a source of many bugs - that is to say, since the number is hard-coded, if you decide to have fewer or more balls per draw, you need to remember and track down the location of all places that refer to the number of balls in the draw - you're much better off using a variable for this, just setting its value once in the program.

You can also make the declaration of your arrays 1-liners too, instead of the 7 that they currently take.

I realize that much of this is not strictly related to your problem, though they make the code infinitely easier to understand, reduce the quantity of it and make it easier to debug.
As such, I've left the calls to `document.write` as-is. It's not a recommended way to put content on the page, I'll let you look into this at a later time.

Here's the results of a quick edit of the code. The number of matches is accurately reported now. I've commented-out draw2 and draw3 for the sake of reduced info on the screen during playing (testing). Notice that the three blocks are much more similar now? You could easily make another function that took as input (a) the guessArray and (b) the drawArray - You could just call it three times in a row, specifying drawOne then drawTwo and finally, drawThree.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Assessment - Lotto Checker</title>
<script>
var maxElems = 6;       // number of elements in (a) the hard-coded draw and (b) the user's guess-array.

function guessChecker(drawArray, guessArray)
{
    var drawIndex, guessIndex, matchCount;
    matchCount = 0;
    for (drawIndex=0; drawIndex<maxElems; drawIndex++)
    {
        for (guessIndex=0; guessIndex<maxElems; guessIndex++)
        {
            if (drawArray[drawIndex] == guessArray[guessIndex])
                matchCount++;
        }
    }
    return matchCount;
}

var date = new Date();
var n = date.toDateString();
var time = date.toLocaleTimeString();
var count2;
var drawOne = new Array(8,11,19,23,28,36);
var drawTwo = new Array(2,9,16,26,39,41)
var drawThree = new Array(7,14,22,30,37,49)
var guess = new Array();
var bonus = 45;
var bonusGuess;

</script>

</head>
<body>
    <script>
    //  do  
    //  {
            guess[0] = window.prompt("Enter your first number:"); 
            guess[1] = window.prompt("Enter your second number:");
            guess[2] = window.prompt("Enter your third number:");
            guess[3] = window.prompt("Enter your fourth number:");
            guess[4] = window.prompt("Enter your fifth number:");
            guess[5] = window.prompt("Enter your sixth number:");
            bonusGuess = window.prompt("Enter Your Bonus Ball:");

            /*-----------------------------
            Draw 1
            ------------------------------*/
            document.write("The Numbers Drawn this week were: ", drawOne, " The Bonus Ball Was: ",bonus, "<br/>")
            document.write("Your Numbers Are: ", guess, " Your Bonus Ball Is: ", bonusGuess, "<br/>")
            var drawOneMatches = guessChecker(drawOne, guess);

            if (drawOneMatches>=5 && bonusGuess == bonus)
                document.write("You Matched ", drawOneMatches, " Numbers! You have also matched the Bonus Ball!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            else if (drawOneMatches>=3)
                document.write("You Matched ", drawOneMatches, " Numbers!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            if(drawOneMatches<3)
                document.write("You Matched ", drawOneMatches, " Numbers! You haven't won this time!</br>")

            document.write((n + ' ' + time), "</br>");
            document.write("</br>")


            /*
            //-----------------------------
            // Draw 2
            //------------------------------
            document.write("The Numbers Drawn this week were: ", drawTwo, " The Bonus Ball Was: ",bonus, "<br/>");
            document.write("Your Numbers Are: ", guess, " Your Bonus Ball Is: ", bonusGuess, "<br/>")
            var drawTwoMatches = guessChecker(drawTwo, guess);
            if(drawTwoMatches>=5 && bonusGuess == bonus)
                document.write("You Matched ", drawTwoMatches, " Numbers! You have also matched the Bonus Ball!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            else if (drawTwoMatches>=3)
                document.write("You Matched ", (drawTwoMatches), " Numbers!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            if(drawTwoMatches<3)
                document.write("You Matched ", (drawTwoMatches), " Numbers! You haven't won this time!</br>")

            document.write((n + ' ' + time), "</br>");
            document.write("</br>")


            //-----------------------------
            //Draw 3
            //------------------------------
            document.write("The Numbers Drawn this week were: ", drawThree, " The Bonus Ball Was: ",bonus, "<br/>");
            document.write("Your Numbers Are: ", guess, " Your Bonus Ball Is: ", bonusGuess, "<br/>")
            var drawThreeMatches = guessChecker(drawThree, guess);
            if(drawThreeMatches>=5 && bonusGuess == bonus)
            {
                document.write("You Matched ", (drawThreeMatches), " Numbers! You have also matched the Bonus Ball!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")
            }

            else if (drawThreeMatches>=3)
                document.write("You Matched ", (drawThreeMatches), " Numbers!</br>You Have won a Prize!!</br>")

            if(drawThreeMatches)
            {
                document.write("You Matched ", (drawThreeMatches), " Numbers! You haven't won this time!</br>")
            }
*/                          
            document.write((n + ' ' + time), "</br>");
            document.write("</br>")
    //  }
    //  while (guess[i]!=guess[i])
    </script>
</body>
```